# How to create a single data set that contains two data frames using an excel file

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, dataset, adehabitathr

I need to create a single data set from an excel file that looks likes the following picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTAPC.jpg). When I export the file to mimic it in excel, the format does not work correctly. This is what the file looks like when it is exported as an excel [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIhfI.jpg). However, when I mimic the exported file with my own data and upload it to r, it doesn't import correct and mirror that of image 1 as it should. This is what it looks like when I mirror the format and import my data and import it to r (it should look like image 1)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x66Z8.jpg).

```
> puechdesIII
$available
         <180 180-250 >250
Calou    103      60   50
Celi      68      23   46
Kinou    114      52   94
Lucette   65      45  269
Schnock   75      35    8
Suzanne  115      76   72

$used
        <180 180-250 >250
Calou     40       8    5
Celi      13       2    8
Kinou     21       4    8
Lucette   15       3   33
Schnock   42       5    0
Suzanne   34      12    5
```

Code used with the given dataset:

```
puechdesIII
data(puechdesIII)
used <- puechdesIII$used
available <- puechdesIII$available
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming puechdessIII is a dataframe class object but it doesn't look like it. If it is try this:

```
available<-puechdesIII$available
used<-puechdesIII$used
names(available) <- c("x", "y", "z")
names(used) <- c("x", "y", "z")
combined.df<-rbind(available, used)
```

next time please provide a usable sample of your data to help us better understand and help.

After your comment, try this:

```
data<-data("puechdesIII")
x<-as.data.frame(puechdesIII)
x1<-x[,4:6]
x2<-x[,1:3]
names(x1) <- c("180", "180.250", "250")
names(x2) <- c("180", "180.250", "250")
df<-rbind(x1,x2)
type<-c(rep("Available",6), rep("Used",6))
frame<-cbind(df,type)
```

Comment: puechdesIII is a dataset that is available through the adehabitatHS package. I have also updated the question above with the data.